# Binary Tree numLeaf algorithm not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a program to try and get the number of leaves in a binary tree. What I did was I checked if the current ptr was a leaf, and if not, to keeps going to the next subtree. However, when I run it, it keeps returning 2. What am I doing wrong?

I didn't include the source code because its relatively standard (has a rLink, lLink, etc.). There are no errors when I run this:

```
template <class elemType>
long int bSearchTreeType<elemType>::getLeaves(nodeType<elemType> * current, long int count) const {
    if(current->rLink == NULL && current->lLink == NULL) {
        count += 1;
        return count;
    }
    if(current->rLink!=NULL) {
        getLeaves(current->rLink);
    }
    if(current->lLink!=NULL) {
        getLeaves(current->lLink);
    }
}

template <class elemType>
long int bSearchTreeType<elemType>::leaves() const {
    if(this->root!=NULL) {
        return this->getLeaves(this->root);
    }
}
```

Edit: I declared the function with count = 1 in the parameter list. Thats why I'm able to to that.

Comment: In both functions the first if-statement returns something. The others do not, but a non-void function must **always** end in a `return value;`.

Comment: First get the code to compile without warnings. I think you will figure it out when you do that.  If not, post a MCVE.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The compiler doesn't give any warnings

Comment: I was also surprised when that happened (non-allinclusive return statement). I think the compiler might have given an implicit return value (I use GDB)

Comment: `getLeaves` takes in two parameters and this method only takes one. Is this the correct one you are sharing here?

Comment: I forgot to tell you: I signatured getLeaves with count set implicitly (int he function parameter list) to 1

Answer (score 0):

I find a few issues.

1) You are calling `return this->getLeaves(this->root);` but there is no method with that method signature in the code sample you have here.
`bSearchTreeType<elemType>::getLeaves(nodeType<elemType> * current, long int count)`

2) Your code doesn't handle cases where the `current` can be null i.e) for tree's like

```
       2
      /
     1
```

3) You are not returning anything after traversing the left and the right sub tree.

You could write something like this

```
template <class elemType>
long int bSearchTreeType<elemType>::getLeaves(nodeType<elemType> * current) 
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(current->rLink == NULL && current->lLink == NULL) 
        return 1;
    int leftSubTree = getLeaves(current->lLink);
    int rightSubTree = getLeaves(current->rLink);
    return leftSubTree + rightSubTree;
}
```